# Google Geomap chart NOT visualizing on mobile

Tags: android, charts, geomap

I'm using geomap chart from google but it seems that it doesn't visualize/work on mobile (Android 4.2 & Chrome browser and/or Webview android app).
Does anyone experienced this kind of problem? Solutions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, or can you provide more detail?  It's going to be hard for people to help without more information.

Comment: No error, only blank page. Even if I browse the google page (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap) the map example doesn't appear.

Comment: After some test I move forward: it seems that Geomap isn't suported/visible on Mobile. Using Geochart, instead, the relavive char is visible but it seems that "region" parameters is not supported (no possibility to map Italian region using dataMode:regions and region:IT)